# Compile error with max_min.c:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `max_func'

Tags: c, linux

I created simple max and min func to show max value and min value from user inputs but I got below error. could you please give me any help?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void max_func(int i, int j);
void min_func(int i, int j);

void main(void)
{

        int i, j;
        scanf ("%d %d", &i, &j);

        max_func (i, j);
        min_func (i, j);

        void max_func (int i, int j)
        {
                if (i > j)
                        printf("Max Value is %d", i);
                else
                        printf("Max Value is %d", j);
        }

        void min_func(int i, int j)
        {
                if (i < j)
                        printf("Min Value is %d", i);
                else
                        printf("Min Value is %d", j);
        }
}


ubuntu:~$ gcc max_min.c -o max.out
/tmp/ccxQ242Y.o: In function `main':
max_min.c:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `max_func'
max_min.c:(.text+0x4b): undefined reference to `min_func'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max_func()` and `min_func()` are not supposed to be inside `main(void){ ... }`

The definitions i.e.:

```
void max_func(int i,int j){
    if ( i>j )
        printf("Max Value is %d", i);
    else
        printf("Max Value is %d", j);
}
```

(and similar for max_func) should be after the closing `}` of `main()`.